# Installing python isopleths module

Tags: python

I wonder if there is anybody who is able to use the tephi module in python to plot tephigrams. When I try i get the error that there is no module isopleths. I have tried to install isopleths with pip as follows

```
pip install --upgrade isopleths
```

and I get the following

```
Collecting isopleths
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement isopleths (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for isopleths
```

with anaconda

```
conda install isopleths
```

I get

```
Fetching package metadata ...........
PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:
- isopleths
We have searched for the packages in the following channels:
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-32
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-32
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/linux-32
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-32
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
```

If anybody has any experience of how to find this module, I would appreciate if they could share

Comment: We can't help you install a package when no one knows what package you're trying to install. I suggest you search for it on [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi). Or perhaps you're looking for this: http://tephi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tephi/tephi/isopleths.html

Comment: Sorry I do not understand the above comment. The link given in the comment is on what the tephi plotting can do. There is no information on how to install the isopleths module which is refered to in the file /home/zmumba/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tephi/__init__.py, specifically line 36 which says import isopleths. It is the isopleths module am looking for. Thanks

Comment: `isopleths` is a sub-module of the `tephi` package. You can't just `import isopleths` from outside of `tephi`. You need to `pip install tephi` and `import tephi.isopleths`.

Comment: ok I think mine is a path problem, because I can see isopleths.py though there is a complaint that there is no module isopleths.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem.

It's a path issue, probably arising from the way pip installed tephi or a confliction with a pre-existing attempt to install it. Although there are conda entries for other scitools packages, there doesn't seem to be one for tephi. I think the best thing is to install it directly from the scitools library on github, that way it'll be up-to-date.

Just do

`git clone https://github.com/SciTools/tephi.git`

```
cd tephi
python setup.py install
```

Be sure before installing that there are no pre-existing `tephi` directories (I had to remove a relic directory called `tephi-0.1.0.dist-info` before it worked) and make sure you've activated the right conda environment (if relevant).